# C: Merge-Sort of an array with uneven number of elements

Tags: c, recursion, merge, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I've been working on an assignment for my *Procedural Programming* class where we are provided with a merge-sort program that does not function completely. It performs a merge-sort on arrays with an even number of integers, but throws a segmentation fault with an odd number of integers.

I understand how the sorting works, and that the segmentation fault is being thrown because the odd number is causing the segmentation fault because the array is being over-filled somehow. I also understand that the solution is going to involve a test for whether or not the original array is even or odd, and then pass the values to the merge function differently depending on this. Despite what I do understand about the program, I have been banging my head against the wall for weeks trying to get this to work properly, and I'm hoping someone can give me some advice.

I've done a lot of looking around for answers before posting this, but all other examples involve merge-sort programs with structs, which is beyond what I've learned so far. You'll see in the code I post below. Also, the full program involves a few other files, but I've included just the `mergesort.c` file and the `merge.c` file which, as I've been assured by my professor, are the only places any changes need to be made. The `main` file works perfectly and is only responsible for filling the array and calling the `mergesort` function. If the other files are necessary, let me know and I'll post them. The only reason I haven't is because we are using a Linux shell, and I haven't found a practical way to copy and paste code from the shell to my own operating system, and it takes a while to write it out.

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can provide. Here is the code.

**mergesort.c**

```
#include <"mergesort.h">

void mergesort(int key[], int n) //key is the array, n is the size of key
{
    int j, k, m, *w;

    w = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(w != NULL);

    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - k; j += 2 * k) {
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            key[j] = w[j];
        }   
    }
    free(w);
}
```

**merge.c**

```
#include "mergesort.h"

void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int m, int n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < m && j < n) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) {
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }   
    }

    while (i < m) {
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < n) {
        c[k++] = b[j++];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works for **all arrays with an even size** ?? I have the feeling it only works for arrays with a size that is a power of 2

Comment: and also what are you allowed to change in the code?? Can you for example rewrite the whole mergesort function?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am able to change anything, but I've been informed by the instructor that changes should only need to be made in the mergesort.c file. Also, yes you're correct. It sorts arrays with a power of two only. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

- The include preprocessor directive is incorrect, either use `#include "mergesort.h"` or `#include <mergesort.h>`.
- You must compute the size of the arrays passed to `merge()` correctly so it does not read beyond the end of the last chunk. As currently coded, `n` must be a power of `2` to avoid undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected version of `mergesort.c` for your purpose:

```
#include "mergesort.h"

void mergesort(int key[], int n) {
    // key is the array, n is the number of elements
    int i, j, k, m;
    int *w;

    // allocate the working array
    w = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    // abort the program on allocation failure
    assert(w != NULL);

    // for pairs of chunks of increasing sizes
    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        // as long as there are enough elements for a pair
        for (j = 0; j + k < n; j = j + k + m) {
            // compute the size of the second chunk: default to k
            m = k;
            if (j + k + m > n) {
                // chunk is the last one, size may be smaller than k
                m = n - j - k;
            }
            // merge adjacent chunks into the working array
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, m);
            // copy the resulting sorted list back to the key array
            for (i = 0; i < k + m; i++) {
                key[j + i] = w[j + i];
            }
        }
    }
    free(w);
}
```

Here are some additional remarks about this exercise, but you might not be advanced enough and changing the API is probably not allowed:

- Using 2 different source files seems overkill.  The `merge` routine is an auxiliary function that deserves to be `static`. It will be expanded inline by modern compilers.
- Array sizes should be passed as `size_t` just after the corresponding pointer (for consistency).
- Instead of asserting the allocation success, you should return a failure code and let the caller handler the failure gracefully.
- You can use the start of the working array for all merge operations. This improves cache efficiency.

Here is a version with all these changes:

```
#include "mergesort.h"

static void merge(int a[], size_t m, int b[], size_t n, int c[]) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < m && j < n) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) {
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < m) {
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < n) {
        c[k++] = b[j++];
    }
}

int mergesort(int key[], size_t n) { 
    // key is the array, n is the size of key
    // return 0 for success, -1 for failure with error code in errno
    size_t i, j, k, m;
    int *w;

    w = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if (w == NULL)
        return -1;

    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        for (j = 0; j + k < n; j += k + m) {
            m = k;
            if (j + k + m > n) {
                m = n - j - k;
            }
            merge(key + j, k, key + j + k, m, w + j);
            // copy the sorted chunk back to the key array
            for (i = 0; i < k + m; i++) {
                key[j + i] = w[i];
            }
        }
    }
    free(w);
    return 0;
}
```

You can further improve the implementation by removing almost half the tests on the index variables in function `merge()`:

```
static void merge(int a[], size_t m, int b[], size_t n, int c[]) {
    /* always called with m > 0 and n > 0 */
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;;) {
        if (a[i] < b[j]) {
            c[k++] = a[i++];
            if (i == m) {
                while (j < n) {
                    c[k++] = b[j++];
                }
                break;
            }
        } else {
            c[k++] = b[j++];
            if (j == n) {
                while (i < m) {
                    c[k++] = a[i++];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can improve `mergesort` and `merge` with these further ideas:

- comparing the last element of `a` and the first element of `b` in `merge` allows vast speed improvements on partially or totally sorted arrays.
- `merge` could return the number of elements to copy back, removing all copying in the sorted case.
- by copying the left chunk to the temporary array and merging into the `key` array, you can reduce the size of the temporary array.
- merging balanced chunk sizes instead of powers of 2 reduces the total number of comparisons for non power of 2 array sizes, but it is easier to implement with a recursive approach.

Comment: I agree with your analysis that `#include <"mergesort.h">` is an error — but I note that in theory, you could have a file with double quotes as part of the name and then the original `#include` would include that file, if it is in a directory on the path that will be searched by the `<>` notation (e.g. with `-I.` on the command line).  OTOH, said file is going to be a persistent pain in the posterior for all and sundry and whoever tried such a trick should be … shunned until they repent of their evil ways.   No, it's not a real quibble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: good idea for obfuscation: make a separate file with surrounding quotes in the name hidden somewhere else in the include path and stash different definitions in there.  I wonder how many code reviews this would resist.

Comment: There still appears to be an issue with your `mergesort` for arrays of unequal length. (if it was to remedy that issue) for example: try with `int a[] = { 9, 3, 1, 7, 5 }, b[] = { 4, 2, 8, 0, 10, 6 };` the `6` is left out in the cold...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `mergesort()` should not be calling merge with such a split, the length of `a` is always a power of 2. And when calling `merge`, both `a[]` and `b[]` are already sorted. Do you mean to test both arrays?

Comment: That's where I was unclear, and why I qualified the comment with *if it was to remedy the issue*. All good. Thanks.

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing: did the answer help you?

Comment: I tried this code and I am unfortunately not getting the sorted array. My input for the array is {67, 55, 8, 0, 4, -5, 37, 7, 4, 2, 9, 1, -1} and the output is -5, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, -1, 4, -1, 1, 2, 4, -1. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Also, to clarify where I'm at in my understanding, I followed everything you explained up until the point where m was passed to merge() as the last value. If the array is a value of 2, wouldn't that value be 0? And wouldn't it be 1 if the the array is not a value of 2? At least at the end of the first pass?

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing: Got it! there was another flaw in my fix: when there is a single chunk at the end of the `key` array (if `j + k < n` is false), the end of temporary array is not updated, therefore copying that back to `key` is incorrect.  I corrected the answer by moving the copy code inside the loop, increasing locality and therefore cache effectiveness.

Comment: I really appreciate your tenacity here, lol. I copied the first block of code (the corrected version as captioned above it) and now what I'm getting is all 0's and then the 55 and 67 at the end (using the same array). I noticed that the else statement disappeared in this version, could that be the issue? I think I can see what you're trying to do here, but I'm still trying to map out the changes myself, and when I do I'll also try to work out what's causing this issue.

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing: OK, I modified the `mergesort` function again, which should be named differently because it conflicts with a similar function from `<stdlib.h>` on BSD systems such as OS/X.  I reverted to incrementing `j` in the `for` statement by the size of the chunk pair and commented the code for clarity.

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm. I'm going to take the time to break it down now and figure out what's happening at every step. Thanks for all your time and multiple efforts.

Comment: @TheStyxCrossing:  Absolutely! mechanics and programming work the same: the best way to learn is to take things apart, see how it all works, and put it back together, check if it still works, and find ways to make it work better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So I've found where your the segmentation error is comming from. If you take a closer look to the first inner for-loop in your mergesort:

```
        for(j = 0; j < n - k; j += 2 * k)
        {
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        }
```

you'll notice that the condition does not really coincide with what you are giving to the merge function as boundaries for your slices of the array. The condition is `j < n - k` so the max value of `j` is `n - k - 1`. But in the arguments of your merge the second array-slice you pass starts at `key + j + k` and you tell it has size `k`, so you end up at index `j + k + k - 1`, if you replace your `j` by its maximum value you get `n - k - 1 + k + k - 1 = n`. Which means that you are telling the merge-function he can go till index `n`. Since the size of key is n, it has no index n. So how do you have to rewrite your condition? We just calculated the maximum index the merge will be accessing: `j + k + k - 1`. So it means you just have to set `j + k + k - 1 < n` as condition. this means:

```
        for(j = 0; j <= n - (k*2); j += 2 * k)
        {
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        }
```

Now we got rid of the segmentation faults, we can go to the second part: making it work for all sizes. The reason why it does only work for sizes wich are a power of 2 (not even all even sizes: try sorting this [2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1] you'll see) is because of your `k`. It is `k` that sets the determines the size of the slices that will be merged in the loop. `k` gets multiplied by 2 after each round, so it will only gets sizes that are a power of 2! When it's not a power of 2, it will just ignore the part that gets "over" the power of 2...if you get what I mean? Before we made that change that solved the segmentation error it would have just tried to do it but fail for that reason (and return an error).
The thing we have to do now is to make it sort that last slice he just ignores. I'll only copy the mergesort-function as it is the only thing that will change:

```
void mergesort(int key[], int n) //key is the array, n is the size of key
{
    int j, k, neglected, *w;
    w = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(w != NULL);

    for(k = 1; k < n; k *= 2){
        for(j = 0; j <= n - (k*2); j += 2 * k){
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k);
        }

        //size of part that got neglected (if it could fully be divided in slices of 2*k, this will be 0)
        neglected = n % (2*k);

        //copy everything except the neglected part (if there was none, it will copy everything)
        for(j = 0; j < n-neglected; ++j) {
            key[j] = w[j];
        }

        if(neglected != 0 && neglected < n){ //couldn't devide it fully in slices of 2*k ==> the last elements were left out! merge them together with the last merged slice 
            merge(key + n - (2*k) - neglected, key + n-neglected, w + n - (2*k) - neglected, 2*k, neglected);
            for(j = n - (2*k) - neglected; j < n; ++j) { //copy the part we just merged
                key[j] = w[j];
            }
        }

        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            key[j] = w[j];
        }
    }
    free(w);
}
```

Also, my compiler was complaining about a variable you weren't using: `m`

Comment: This is great and makes a lot of sense. My only question is, why is neglected being assigned the value of the modulus of (n % 2*k) and n? Aren't you always going to get a number less than 0 at that point and couldn't you just assign neglected the modulus of n and 2*k? Thanks again for you help.

Comment: It is because it can happen that 2*k > n. In that case n%(2*k) would be n thus neglected = n. This means that the array is just not big enough to get 2 slices of size k and merge them together (at each iteration, slices of size k are merged together). What does that say about the iteration just before it? Let's call the k of the iteration just before it `k'` (explanation continues in following comment)

Comment: As k doubles after each iteration, `k'` is just a bit bigger than n/2. This means that at the previous iteration (the one with `k'`) the array was just big enough to get 2 slices of size `k'` ( besides the neglected part at that iteration) and merge them together in one big merged slice. The neglected part at that iteration (if there was one) would then be merged with that big part => whole array is merged! So this means, if neglected is n, it means 2*k > n which means the array has already been merged completely in the previous iteration!

Comment: I was actually just looking for a way to then tell that actually there was no neglected part anymore so I came up with modulus n which will make it 0 again. I hope this helped you understand it but you just made me realize it wasn't a that good idea because just after that it will let the loop copy the whole array again. So I just edited my answer, left out the modulus n part and put it an extra condition for the if-clause which would merge the neglected part (but now you know why). Thanks for that! If something is not clear enough, other questions are always welcome.

Comment: Again, I apologize for the delay here, the holiday weekend has been a little hectic. What you're saying makes perfect sense. I'm going to give it a go ASAP.