# C - Why is this program printing two 0's?

Tags: c, merge

Here is the program. It takes a hardcoded set of integers and sorts them from least to greatest. I copied it from a book and I can't for the life of my decipher how it does what it does so maybe someone can help me understand.

**MAIN**

```
/* Test merge() and mergesort(). */

#include "mergesort.h"

int main(void) {
    int sz, key[] = {67, 55, 8, 0, 4, -5, 37, 7, 4, 2, 9, 1, -1};

    sz = sizeof(key) / sizeof(int);
    printf("Before mergesort:");
    wrt(key, sz);
    mergesort(key, sz);
    printf("After mergesort:");
    wrt(key, sz);
    return 0;
}
```

**MERGE.C**

```
/* Merge a[] of size m and b[] of size n into c[]. */
#include "mergesort.h"
void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < m && j < n)
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            c[k++] = b[j++];
    while (i < m)   /* pick up an remainder */
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    while (j < n)
        c[k++] = b[j++];
}
```

**MERGESORT.C**

```
/* Mergesort: Use merge() to sort an array of size n. */

#include "mergesort.h"
void mergesort(int key[], int n) // n is 0 to begin with
{
    int j,k,m, *w;
    int x,y;

    for (m = 1; m < n; m *= 2)      /*m is a power of 2*/
        if (n < m){
            printf("ERROR: Array size not a power of 2 - bye!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    w = calloc(m, sizeof(int));     /* allocate workspace */
    assert(w != NULL);             /* check that calloc() worked */
    for (k = 1; k < n; k *= 2) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - k; j += 2 * k)
            /*
              Merge two subarrays of key[] into a subarray of w[].
            */
            merge(key + j, key + j + k, w + j, k, k); // todo: make the two k's not equal
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            key[j] = w[j];
    }


    free(w);
}
```

**MERGESORT.H**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int m, int n);
void mergesort(int key[], int n);
void wrt(int key[] , int sz);
```

**WRT.C**

```
#include "mergesort.h"

void wrt(int key[], int sz)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        printf("%4d%s", key[i], ((i < sz - 1) ? "" : "\n"));
}
```

When it's printed out, there are two zeroes. How is this happening? I think the secret to this lies in mergesort.c, with the k value. As you can see near the bottom, I commented in "todo: make the two k's not equal", this is the simplified solution my teacher offered for me. I also put in the x and y ints which will be the separate k values. But I don't understand, how can I split this one value into two?

Comment: Get in the habit of not using 1-letter variable names.  In merge, change m,n to sizea, sizeb and change i,j,k to indexa, indexb, indexc.

Comment: @stark 1-letter variable names aren't inherently bad. They are bad when they are not descriptive enough. Replacing `i` and `j` with `indexa` and `indexb` is just as bad if not worse since pretty much everyone understands that `i`, `j`, and `k` are loop iterators.

Comment: Do not use `assert()` to check for runtime errors.  It is for testing conditions whose falsehood would signal a *programming* error.  You cannot safely rely on the expression within ever being evaluated (it depends on compilation details).

Comment: Whereas I'm inclined to agree that single-letter variable names are not *always* bad, there are a lot of them in your code that interfere significantly with understanding what the code does.  It would be a useful exercise to change the names to more meaningful ones, especially those of the function parameters.  To do that, of course, have to study the code to figure out what names would be meaningful, but that's part of the usefulness of the exercise.

Comment: I would recommend changing the `key` array to something smaller, maybe of size 2 or 4, and seeing what the code does by stepping through it in a debugger, or adding lots of printfs of you don't know how to use a debugger yet.

Comment: How do you expect us to reproduce your problem?  Amongst other things, there is no `main()` function

Comment: to avoid problems (of which non-protected header files can cause many problems.)  Always write your headers similar to: `#ifndef MERGESORT_H  #define MERGESORT_H  <rest of the header file>  #endif // MERGESORT_H`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`: 1) those functions are expecting all the parameters to be of type `size_t`.  Regarding: `w = calloc(m, sizeof(int));`  the parameter `m` is declared as an `int` rather than as a `size_t`

Comment: in the function: `mergesort()` there is the unused variable `y` and the unused variable `x`.  You should either remove them or fix the code so they are properly used.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: do NOT use `assert()` to check if the function: `calloc` was successful, Suggest: `if( !w ) { perror( "calloc failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }

Comment: please use a search engine, like `google` to find a 'good' implementation, in C, of the `merge-sort` algorithm.

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like: a[] b[] c[] m, etc etc are meaningless, even in the current context.  Programs should be written so they inform the reader of what is being done, not to confuse the reader with cryptic/meaningless names

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files within header files unless the rest of the header file is using the contents of the included header file.

Comment: the function: `wrt()`  is not called from anywhere

Comment: for your own piece of mind, do not leave out optional opening/closing braces.   It is way to easy, when debugging or maintaining the code to destroy the execution sequence of the code when the optional braces are not used

Comment: since when, is it a requirement that an array in a sort merge operation having to be a power of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part of code of function `mergesort()`:

```
    for (m = 1; m < n; m *= 2)      /*m is a power of 2*/
    if (n < m){
        printf("ERROR: Array size not a power of 2 - bye!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

This is supposed to check whether the size of the array, to be sort, is having the size in power of `2` and the size of the array you are passing is `13` (not the power of `2`):

```
int sz, key[] = {67, 55, 8, 0, 4, -5, 37, 7, 4, 2, 9, 1, -1};
```

it should throw error and exit but since the `power of 2` check is incorrect it proceeds further and **your merge sort code is not capable of sorting an array of uneven size**. Hence, you are getting the incorrect output for the array of uneven size.

In the `for` loop

```
for (m = 1; m < n; m *= 2) 
            ^^^^^
```

the loop will iterate till `m < n` and the in the loop body `if` condition you are checking

```
if (n < m){ ....
```

which will never happen because as soon as `m > n` the loop will exit.

Instead of checking the power of `2`, I believe you want to check whether the size of the array is `even` or not.
To check whether the size is *even* or not you can simply do:

```
   if (n & 1)
   {
       printf("ERROR: Array size not a multiple of 2 - bye!\n");
       exit(1);
   }
```

For sorting an array using merge sort, it's not required that the size of the array should be **even**. You can use merge sort to sort an array of **odd** size as well. Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796394/c-merge-sort-of-an-array-with-uneven-number-of-elements).